# Can a random forest model be extracted for practical use?

Tags: modeling, random-forest, communication

I'm new to random forest models and have questions.

When I develop a linear model, I can tell people "Hey kids- here's how to predict the circumference of a circle if you know the radius.  Just plug the radius into this handy formula: A = 2 * pi * radius.  They don't have to know any stats at all to go start calculating circumferences.

But, if I have a random forest model, how can I communicate to folks how they can predict their own values with their own data?  Do I have to distribute my original dataset to them so they can run an R/Python script?  Or is there a way to extract foresty-equivalent of coefficients and slopes?  I suppose it would be the decision tree somehow. Could it ever get to something like a convoluted Excel formula I could share in a spreadsheet template?  How does the average person (not the statistician) actually *use* these things in the real world?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options:

### 1) Loading trained model

Frameworks like sklearn make it easy to persist the trained estimator to disk, and then to load it up afterwards. One would distribute a Python script which uses the trained model, as well as doing any data pre and post-processing. The training data is then not needed.

From the [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html):

Training

```
from sklearn import ensemble, datasets
from sklearn.externals import joblib
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
joblib.dump(clf, 'rf-model.pkl')
```

Predictions

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
clf = joblib.load('rf-model.pkl')
clf.predict(Xnew)
```

Implementations of Random Forest will have a way to get the trained cofficients, but the details vary a lot. Fundamentally a Random Forest classifier is a number of trees. Each tree does classification by executing a bunch of if-else statements, each checking whether one of the variables is below. At the leaf is the returned class label. The trees are combined using (weighted) majority voting.

### 2) Generating code

Using [emtrees](https://github.com/jonnor/emtrees) one can export random forests trained with sklearn as C code. A bit simplified, it looks like:

```
int32_t digits_predict_tree_0(int32_t *features, int32_t features_length)
{
  if (features[36] < 32768) {
      if (features[57] < 65536) {
          return 9;
      } else {
          if (features[10] < 950272) {
              return 5;
  ....
}

int32_t digits_predict(int32_t *fe, int32_t features_length)
{
   _class = digits_predict_tree_1(fe, length); votes[_class] += 1;
   _class = digits_predict_tree_2(fe, length); votes[_class] += 1;
   ....
   return find_majority(votes);
}
```

The same could be done for other languages, theoretically even an Excel macro.

### 3) Providing webservice

A modern alternative is to set up a simple webservice where users can drop their input data (as .CSV/.xsl), and then download the returned predictions as a new file.

Comment: Didn't know about the compile to C thing.  Very cool.